# iOS: How to move UITableViewCellAccessory Button to the left

Tags: ios, ipad, uitableview, accessorytype

I'm trying to develop a UITableView which has sectionIndexTitles and which cells have accessory buttons.

The problem is that the scrollbar for the index titles decreases the width of the cells and so the accessory buttons are at an ugly position...

Is it possible to move the button slightly to the left that they are inside the cell?

```
- (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        cell.textLabel.text = @"text";
    }

    return cell;
}
```

As you can see I don't manipulate the cell or something like that.

And here you can see the result:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3AB89.jpg

Comment: actually i manipulated the code that there are none of the additional custom lines (i've tested it without these -> same result)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way to move default accessoryView, but its pretty hacky. So it might stop working one day when new sdk arrives.

Use at your own risk (this code snippet moves any accessoryView 8 pixels to the left, insert it inside -(void)layoutSubviews method of desired uitableviewcell subclass):

```
if (self.accessoryView) {
    r = self.accessoryView.frame;
    r.origin.x -= 8;
    self.accessoryView.frame = r;
} else {
    UIView* defaultAccessoryView = nil;
    for (UIView* subview in self.subviews) {
        if (subview != self.textLabel && 
            subview != self.detailTextLabel && 
            subview != self.backgroundView && 
            subview != self.contentView &&
            subview != self.selectedBackgroundView &&
            subview != self.imageView) {
            defaultAccessoryView = subview;
            break;
        }
    }
    r = defaultAccessoryView.frame;
    r.origin.x -= 8;
    defaultAccessoryView.frame = r;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your response! first of all: it worked! thanks!
having a look on the default behavious (without this hack) i noticed that on the iPhone the cells aren't resized when there is a section titles scrollbar but the accessory buttons are moved to the left nicely, but on the iPad the complete opposite happens: the cells are resized and the accessory buttons aren't ... do you know why this happens?

Comment: That is odd. First, TBH I wouldn't recommend that code at all. It is a hack and can break at any time. The BEST way to do this, is get your own UITableViewCellAccessory image, then add it to the cell using addSubview and adjust the frame using that. That is the easiest way since there is no built in way to adjust the frame of the UITableViewAccessory.